# Is $\sigma(-\Delta)=\sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(-\Delta)$? Or under which conditions do we have this?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, spectral-theory, laplacian

Let $\Delta: H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$
be the Laplace operator in the weak sense.

A Lemma in the book of Borthwick (Spectral Theory) says:

[image]

It is proved, by showing that $\sigma_{ess}(-\Delta)=\sigma_{ess}(-\Delta+V)$. Then it is said that the claim follows.

> But why? Is $\sigma_{ess}(-\Delta)=\sigma(-\Delta)$?

So far I know $\sigma(\Delta)=(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: By the Fourier transform the (negative) Laplacian is unitarily equivalent to a (unbounded) multiplication operator being the multiplication by $|\xi|^2$. Hence the result follow, since $\lambda+|\xi|^2$ is invertible and it's inverse yields a well defined bounded function iff $\Re \lambda > 0$.

Comment: Okay, so this explains, why the spectrum is how it is, but why is the discrete spectrum empty here?